# Activate range of an inactive workbook

Tags: vba, excel

In the following code:

```
Dim FirstSourceCell As Range
Set FirstSourceCell = Workbooks("Source.xlsx").Worksheets  ("Settlements").Range("M9")

FirstSourceCell.Activate
```

why does the `FirstSourceCell.Activate` works only when the `Source.xlsx` workbook is activated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only activate a cell in the currently active worksheet. So if the workbook isn't active, the worksheet can't be active, therefore you will get an error if you try to activate a cell on that inactive worksheet.

But there are very few cases where a cell needs to be activated. About the only real case is where you want to return control to the user with a specific cell selected. In that case, it is better to use `Application.GoTo FirstSourceCell`.